# I am Getting Presentation Error in Online Program Challenge Compiler

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int num, i, j, result, index;
    char name[100][10]; 
    char temp[10];                 
    scanf("%d\n", &num);
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        scanf("%s\n", name[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) { 
        index = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < num; j++) {
            result = strcmp(name[index], name[j]);
            if(result > 0)                               
                index = j;
        }
        strcpy(temp, name[index]);
        strcpy(name[index], name[i]);                  
        strcpy(name[i], temp);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%s", name[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

You are given a set of words over the lowercase English alphabet. They are to be sorted in alphabetical order.

Alphabetical order : It is the order in which words are organized in a dictionary or in an telephone directory.

For example,

- abc comes before xab. Reason : The first letters differ. So, they are compared. a comes before x in English alphabet.
- aab comes before abc. Reason : The first letters are same (aab abc). So, the next 2 letters are compared (aab abc).
- aab comes before aaba. Reason : The first 3 letters in aab are same as the first 3 letters in aaba and there are no more letters in aab to compare against aaba. So, the word with the smaller length comes first (aab).

Input - The first line has ‘n’, the number of words, followed by n lines each of which contains a word.

Output - Words in alphabetical order, one one each line.

Constraints : 0 < n <=100, 0 < length of each word <= 10

Hint : See how two-dimensional arrays can help.

**This Program Reverts Presentation Error in Online Challenge**

Sample Input

```
2
world
hello
```

Sample Output

```
hello
world
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'This program reverts presentation error'? You can at least combine `printf("%s",name[i]); printf("\n");` into `printf("%s\n", name[i]);`, but that's trivia.

Comment: `name` and `temp` should be `name[100][11]` and `temp[11]`. You forgot about the terminating character `'\0'` as a side note

Comment: Reverts means i am getting Presentation Error but the Output is correct

Comment: `scanf("%d\n", &num);` --> `scanf("%d", &num);` , `scanf("%s\n", name[i]);` --> `scanf("%s", name[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Presentation error simply means that the way you have presented the o/p is not matching with the robo judge's database.
Just find out how the actual o/p shold be presented by making some mistakes in your expected answer and then you can correct it.

Comment: I case of presentation error since our output is correct but not matching with the robo judge's database. Will i get points for this submission since in my case it is giving correct output for given test cases but giving "presentation error" on submission.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
int num, i, j, result, index;

char name[100][11]; 

char temp[11];   

scanf("%d", &num);

for(i = 0; i < num; i++)

scanf("%s", name[i]);

for(i = 0; i < num; i++) 

{ 


index = i;


for(j = i + 1; j < num; j++)

{


result = strcmp(name[index], name[j]);


if(result > 0)                               


index = j;

}


strcpy(temp, name[index]);

strcpy(name[index], name[i]);                  

strcpy(name[i], temp);

}

enter code here

for(i = 0; i < num-1; i++) 

{


printf("%s\n", name[i]);

}

printf("%s", name[i]);

return 0;

}
```