# Why am I getting presentation error in python list?

Tags: python, list, split, integer

### My code is following:

```
d = [int(d) for d in input().split()]

l = []
c = 1
for i in range(len(d)):
    if d[i] not in l:
        l.append(d[i])
        c += 1

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i], end=" ")
```

### Evaluation:

Input    :  1 1 9 5 2 1 4 1 1 4 0 6 1 4 3 3 2 2 0                                   Output   :  1 9 5 2 4 0 6 3
Status   :   *Passed after ignoring Presentation Error*

Comment: likely your output formatting is not the formatting your teacher wants

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748662/i-am-getting-presentation-error-in-online-program-challenge-compiler ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am Getting Presentation Error in Online Program Challenge Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748662/i-am-getting-presentation-error-in-online-program-challenge-compiler)

Comment: What's a presentation error? Can you provide some more context for this? Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

PresentationError is a mixing between some tabs and spaces.
You can delete all "tabs" in your script and rewrite them consistently
or run `python -tt yourscript.py` so you find the error.

As far as I know, you can copy paste your code from your question again
because it worked perfectly for me after copying it.