# python "passed ignoring presentation error" #joy of computing using python

Tags: python, input, output

I have started to learn python recently from joy of computing using python course. While solving coding assignment I got a status of "passed ignoring presentation error". I need help to resolve this [image: CODE SNIPPET]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting presentation error in python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589240/why-am-i-getting-presentation-error-in-python-list)

Comment: Please provide the code as text instead of a picture so that it could be easily tested.